# Is this SQL Injection Vulnerability in Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection

I am working with a stored procedure called GetPublicMethodData, which executes a dynamic SQL query based on user inputs. My manager has pointed out a potential SQL injection vulnerability in the code, and I am seeking guidance on how to address this issue effectively.

Here's the code for calling stored procedure
`Exec GetPublicMethodData 'GetFilterData', N'{"Make_Id": 1}'`

Here's the code for the stored procedure:

```
Create PROCEDURE GetPublicMethodData
    @MethodKeyword NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @ParamKeyword_JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @MethodName NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @MethodId BIGINT = 0;

    SELECT @MethodId = MethodId, @MethodName = MethodName FROM SYS_PublicMethod WHERE MethodKeyword = @MethodKeyword;
    
    SELECT @Result = COALESCE(@Result + ', ', '') + P.Parameter + ' = ' +
        CASE
            WHEN ISJSON([value]) = 1 THEN [value]
            ELSE '''' + [value] + ''''
        END
    FROM OPENJSON(@ParamKeyword_JSON) J
    INNER JOIN SYS_PublicParam P ON P.ParamKeyword COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = J.[key] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    WHERE MethodId = @MethodId

    SET @Query = 'EXEC ' + QUOTENAME(@MethodName) + ' ' + ISNULL(@Result, '');

    EXEC sp_executesql @Query;
END;
```

Based on my understanding, the code seems fine because @Query value will be like EXEC [GetFilterData] @Make_Id = '1'

P.S. I have already replace 1 single quote with 2 single quotes in csharp JSONString.Replace("'","''")

Guidance and recommendations on addressing the SQL injection vulnerability in this stored procedure would be highly valuable. Thank you for your expertise and assistance in resolving this security issue.

Updated:
The requirement was to build a architecture where we don't need to create API for stored procedures. So there is only 1 API which will call all the stored procedures in safe way.

Following is the parameters from POSTman to injection

```
{
    "JSONSTRING": "{\"MakeId\":\"2' Delete From TestPayment\"}"
}
```

@Query value will be

> EXEC [GetFilterData] @Make_Id = '2'' Delete From
> TestPayment'

Comment: This smells like an XY Problem. Why are you doing the above in the first place? Why have a procedure to call another procedure? Why not have the user call `GetFilterData`? Why are you injecting `@Result` and notparametrising the value it?

Comment: Not to mention the syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your in a row by row order, which there is *no* guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using `STRING_AGG`, however, in older versions you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to achieve the same results.

Comment: @ThomA Actually the requirement was to build a architecture where we don't need to create API for stored procedures. So there is only 1 API which will call all the stored procedures in safe way.

Comment: Definitely smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: `CASE WHEN ISJSON([value]) = 1 THEN [value] ELSE '''' + [value] + ''''` the value is not being escaped properly, so that will fail. As a side note: if you want to know the type just use `CASE WHEN J.type IN (4, 5)`. Also `@Result` needs to be `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: *"P.S. I have already replace 1 single quote with 2 single quotes in csharp JSONString.Replace("'","''")"* Great, but what about anyone that executes this procedures from *outside* C#. ***NEVER*** rely on the application layer to sanitise code, as that's only helpful for code from the application; if someone connects to the instance, *nothing* would be sanitised.

Comment: If you're building such a system, you always have a risk of sql injection. The question is if you mitigate it well enough. i would do a couple things: move method name to a own variable, so you can do execute @var, params... and then do a lot of testing with quotes etc if you can get your procedure to crash. as other said, you should probably do at least a quote replace in the procedure itself

Comment: @siggemannen yes correct and I have replaced the single quote in csharp.

Comment: This almost feels like the [Inner platform effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect) where you're taking an existing system that allows you to pass the name of a stored procedure and a number of parameters to it and inside that you're building something that can... take the name of a procedure to run and a number of parameters and execute that procedure. It's unlikely you're going to build something more robust than the system you're already building inside of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of a comment, injection might be possible(there is no single quote to be replaced in Make_Id, yet there are quotes in there)

```
Exec GetPublicMethodData 'GetFilterData', N'{"Make_Id":"1\u0027;SELECT 1234[inject];PRINT\u0027"}'
```

Comment: Depends if `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is on or off. But in general your point stands: there are other angles of attack

Comment: @user21994727 Thanks, any other ways ?